# How to address the pip installation error below in ubuntu

Tags: pip, google-colaboratory

I am trying to run `pip install google-colab` to run some of my models but I keep running into the error below. I have run `pip install -U setuptools` and upgraded it successfully. What steps should I approach to handle the problems below

[image]

Comment: It looks like that version of pandas is specifying an invalid version for the "pytz" package - two things to try are installing pytz yourself before trying to install google-colab, or, try installing a different version of pandas before installing google-colab (and hope that _that_ version of pandas installs cleanly).